# Balanced layout of n items in a grid

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a list of n logos to display in a grid, with a maximum of 3 per row.
What's an algorithm to decide how many to display per row such that the number of logos per row is as balanced as possible without using more than the minimum possible number of rows?

For example:

```
 n -> number in each row
 1 -> 1
 2 -> 2
 3 -> 3
 4 -> 2, 2
 5 -> 3, 2
 6 -> 3, 3
 7 -> 3, 2, 2
 8 -> 3, 3, 2
 9 -> 3, 3, 3
10 -> 3, 3, 2, 2
```

Comment: you're requirements are...missing. Are we supposed to break down the number into smaller parts? By what rules?

Comment: Are you trying to print the possible ways to express your number as a sum? You know there are an infinite number of ways to do that, right?

Comment: the numbers to the right of the arrow sum to the number from the left.  I think he means "if I have 8 logos to display, I want 2 rows of 3 (max 3 in a line) and then I want the remaining 2 on the last line.  But if there are 4, I want a balanced presentation of 2x2."

Comment: What is the max number of logos ? It seems that if you have a small number hard-coding is an answer.

Comment: he wants to bin set into subsets of at most three elements, with a slight twist to ensure bins are balanced (in case of 4)

Comment: The problema arises on 10, Does 10->|3 3 3 1| is a valid answer? Depending on that the algorithm will be different.

Comment: It looks like they want no orphans. Ie: no rows with only 1 logo

Comment: Please note the checkmarks next to the answers. This is how you can accept the answer that best addresses your question's needs. Also, please notice the up and down arrows. This is for up-voting good questions and answers and down-voting bad ones.

Answer (score 12):

- For N <= 3 just use N.
- If N is exactly divisible by 3 then use: 3 3 ... 3
- If N when divided by 3 has remainder 1 then use: 3 3 ... 2 2
- If N when divided by 3 has remainder 2 then use: 3 3 ... 3 2

Comment: How can you use `3 3 ... 2 2` for `4`? Won't this print `3 1` for `4`?

Comment: @IVlad: (4 % 3) == 1 so use 3 3 .. 2 2. Since 2 + 2 = 4, you need no 3's and two 2's.

Answer (score 6):

AS confusing as your question is, I think what you need to do is first determine:

```
number_of_rows = ceil(number_of_logos / 3.0)
```

Then add a logo to each row, one at a time.

Python:

```
import math
def partition_logos(count, lsize):
    num_lines = int(math.ceil(count / float(lsize)))
    partition = [0] * num_lines
    for i in xrange(count):
        partition[i%num_lines] += 1
    return partition

>>> for i in xrange(1,11):
...     print partition_logos(i, 3)
[1]
[2]
[3]
[2, 2]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Another good feature of this solution is that the 3 isn't hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't part of a programmer's job taking ambiguous, poorly specified requirements and distilling them down into a neat, tidy solution? ;)

Answer (score 1):

just use n/3 to calculate the row and n%3 to calculate the column

edit: ok i saw you edited your question.... i din't saw that you want to display 2 in each row if the are 4 logos. but then you can use n mod 3 to calculate if their is a reminder as others already suggested

if n%3 = 0 then just put 3 logos in each row
if n%3 = 1 then put the last 4 logos in two rows
if n%3 = 2 then put 3 logos in n row and the last 2 logos in a separate row

Comment: That would give 3 3 3 1 for 10, where the questioner wants 3 3 2 2 (i.e. try to balance the rows better).

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution, in Python:

```
def logos_by_row(N, rows):
    width = 0
    if N > 4 or N == 3:
        width = 3
    elif N == 4 or N == 2:
        width = 2
    elif N == 1:
        width = 1

    if width != 0:
        rows.append(width)
        logos_by_row(N - width, rows)


answer = []
for i in range(10):
    logos_by_row(i+1, answer)
print answer
```